# Vue Router and Laravel Middleware

Tags: vue-router, middleware

I want to add middleware in vue router, using laravel auth. If auth is checked then it should be allowed to open url otherwise retun back.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: {path: '/', component: HomePage},

Comment: this is the route for home pahe, i want to add this in middleware

Comment: Are you working with a single page application?

Comment: yes. its single page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vue-router` [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

as per your code i will try to add an example

```
{
  path: '/', 
  component: HomePage,
  beforeEnter: requireAuth
}
```

My navigation guard will be `requireAuth` as

```
function requireAuth(to, from, next) {

    if (login) { //you local login check, you can either use vuex or local storage or cookies etc
      next()
    } else {
      next("/login")
    }
  }
```

Comment: where login function is defined ?

Comment: the login is a local check, you can define it where you want, i mostly use vuex storage or local storage

Comment: but i am not using localstorage, i used laravel auth